# How to get correct cell using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache

[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fChe8.png)

I am working on a 2d array which has a length of 8.I want to store all 8 periods of monday & tuesday in that 2d array.How can i do this.I am using Apache POI to access excel.

I searched similar questions but they were not accurate enough according to my needs

Answer (score 1):

The best practice of this forum would be to add what you have tried and point where you got stuck. A generic question as yours would not be encouraged.

Since I have it handy, I am adding the rough steps here.

```
    private String[][] processExcel(Sheet sheet) {
    //initialize whatever dimension of array is required
     String[][] arr = new String[3][3];
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                String day = processCell(0, row);
      /*retrieve what ever info is required based on cell number.*/
            }
            return arr;
        }

    private String processCell(Integer cellNo, Row row) {
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        return formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(cellNo, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)).trim();
    }
```